# Logging in multi-processing and multi-threading python program?

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I am writing the back end of an Online Judge ( code checker) in python 2.7 which takes
submissions from database(using mysql) evaluates the submission and writes the result
back to database.I am running multi processes and each process runs multiple threads.For
time being I am printing the evaluations status and other stuff directly to STDOUT. I haven't
even put lock on printing(which is cumbersome because there are many print statements).Although I know lock is necessary in this condition.But initially my evaluator
had only one process which had only one thread.I did not put lock that time and was redirecting `STDOUT` and `STDERR` to file from command line.But now the case is different.Also
such log would difficult to be read and finding the error and other things if my evaluator crashes.Is there some neat way of logging in this case ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a variable like a counter that is a process or thread counter. So you can check this counter and you can use lock  when counter bigger than 1.

Comment: I guess that won't work I cannot allow threads/processes to simultaneously access this variable counter i would in turn have to put a lock on it.Same problem again.

Comment: Yeap you are right. You have to use lock on it. I think you don't escape use to lock. I am wondering how to solve it.